# WCF client fields are losing values

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted on a console application the code is:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SetField(string data);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetField();
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private string myData;
    public string GetField()
    {
        retrun myData;
    }
    public void SetField(string data)
    {
        myData = data;
    }
}
```

then I hosted it on a console application:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));

host.Open();            

Console.WriteLine("Test Service Host");
Console.WriteLine("Service Started!");

foreach (Uri address in host.BaseAddresses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + address);
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the host...");
Console.ReadLine();

host.Close();
```

I started the console host then In an other console app I referenced the service and used it:

```
TestService client = new TestService();
client.SetField("test");
Console.WriteLine( client.GetField() );
```

this print nothing means the field is still null

What is wrong with this service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is that you're expecting that **state** will be persisted between calls - it is **NOT**. By default, WCF are absolutely **stateless** (and they should be! That's a **good thing!**)

If you need to persist information - store it into a persistent store (a.k.a a **database**).

Each WCF call will (by default) get a brand new, freshly created **instance** of `TestService`.

So your second call's instance knows **nothing** about the first instance (used by `SetField`) and therefore cannot return that value that you set in the first call.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a [ServiceContract] attribute on the ITestService interface?

Comment: @Greg: yes, that would be clearer and would show the intent more clearly. WCF is trying to "compensate" for sloppy and lazy programmers by inferring that from the `[OperationContract]` attributes on the methods.

Comment: @marc_s: if it's stateless, If I run a backgroundWorker async operation, will the operation be complete? and how to know it's in progress?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use string as static.

```
public interface ITestService
{
   [OperationContract]
   void SetField(string data);

   [OperationContract]
   string GetField();
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
  private static string myData;
  public string GetField()
  {
    retrun myData;
  }
  public void SetField(string data)
  {
     myData = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would advise **against** using static fields - really really bad, use a proper persistent store (database!) instead. As it stands now, your code is **not thread-safe**

Answer (score 1):

You should mark your service class with the attribute:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]    
public class TestService : ITestService 
{ 
   //... 
}
```

This means that your service must have only one instance. And you must create the host like this:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(new TestService()); // or get a singleton..
host.Open();
```

Pay your attantion that you use an instance to create a service instead type. Then your code should work.

Comment: I would also **strongly advise** against using the `InstanceContxetMode.Single`: first of all, unless you also specify `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, you basically have a **serialized** service - one request at a time only. If you specify `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, then you need to be **extra careful** when programming to make sure your code is **100% thread-safe!** Not an easy task....

Comment: Thanks for advice, it will be usefull very soon.

Comment: @marc_s: I using another thread as I said before, what if I used InstanceContextMode.PerSession isn't that thread safe?